# Kids book where the main character has metal under his skin

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I read a book when I was in school in the UK, probably around year 2000, all I remember is the main character I think is found by a group of kids and they look after him. He gets increasingly unwell and his skin starts falling off, only to discover he is made of metal underneath the skin (possibly gold or copper). I don’t remember if the other kids have superpowers or not. I just have a visceral memory of this boy shedding his skin to reveal a metal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover of the book?